# Problem with the ring of p-adic integers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I just tried to figure out the meaning of this equation:

"We can write −1 as a p-adic integer:
−1=(p−1)+(p−1)p+(p−1)p^2 +(p−1)p^3 +..."

In which sense is the right side of the equation equal to "-1". For any finite "n" i get the following equation:

(p−1)+(p−1)p+(p−1)p^2 +...+(p−1)p^n = -1+p^n+1 ;

so does the first "equation" mean equal to -1 mod p^n+1 for any finite n?

I just try to find a explicit description for the ring of p-adic integers as set. But i really have trouble with that, because i don't see how we get negative integers with infinite sums of positive integers since the ring of integers seems to be subring.

I apologize for my bad english, also i haven't figured out how this editor works.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: That ellipses at the end means that you need to take the limit. Basically all this is saying is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}-1+p^n=-1.$$ This is true by the definition of $p$-adic metric.

Answer (score 0):

By the geometric series we have
$$
\frac{1}{1-p}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} p^i,
$$
so that
$$
-1=(p-1)(1+p+p^2+\cdots)=(p-1)+(p-1)p+(p-1)p^2+\cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers has a metric $d(x,y) = p^{-\mathrm{ord}_p(x-y)}$ which induces a topology on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (where $\mathrm{ord}_p(x)$ is the highest power of $p$ which divides $x$, or $\infty$ if $x = 0$).  Essentially, this means that a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if $\mathrm{ord}_p(x_n-x) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  Now, the statement says that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (p-1) \cdot p^n = -1$$
in this topology, i.e. the sequence of partial sums converges to $-1$.

As for the question about negative sum vs. positive elements: this just means that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ cannot be given a structure of ordered ring, at least not in a way that interacts well with limits.  (And in fact, for example for $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ turns out to have solutions to $x^2 = -1$ which implies no structure of ordered ring is possible at all in those cases.)

Comment: I see, thanks, that clarifies a lot, so my next question is, how do i find an additive inverse for such an infinite "formal" sum? Do i have to find a Sum, so that the difference converges to zero in this topology, or is there an easier way?

Comment: You can just negate each term of the series.  If what you really want is to take one expression of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n p^n$ with $a_n$ being integers in $[0, p)$, and negate it to get another such expression, you can do a formal "subtraction with carry" in much the same way as you learned to subtract numbers in base 10 in grade school - it's just that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the order of digits is conventionally reversed so you need to go left to right, and the difference will often have infinitely many digits (but finding the first $n$ digits is still the same process).

Comment: I thought about that way too. But i also thought, that for all n the coefficients an has to be non negative. This isn't the case any longer?

Comment: I did give an answer for the case where you want the result to be in normalized form with each $a_n$ being an integer in the range $0 \le a_n < p$.  For example, if $p=5$ and $x=0021401\ldots_5 = 2 \cdot 5^2 + 1 \cdot 5^3 + 4 \cdot 5^4 + 1 \cdot 5^6 + \cdots$, then $-x = 0033043\ldots_5$.

Comment: yap is see, i was just reading it again, i didn't get it the first time cause of the language

Comment: As an *old* hand at this stuff, @DanielSchepler, I urge strongly that $p$-adic expansions be written extending infinitely to the left. Then hand calculation of sums, differences, and products proceeds *exactly* as we learned in elementary school. Long division needs a slightly different strategy, though.